# How to synchronized time between servers?

Tags: ntpd

I tried to synchronize time between 2 machines, but unfortunately I failed to do so. I always got

```
"12 Jan 01:09:55 ntpdate[2477]: no server suitable for synchronization found"
```

error.
I suspect that the resctict option is wrong. My current setting is

```
# Hosts on local network are less restricted.
restrict 192.168.23.140 mask 255.255.255.252 nomodify notrap
```

My ntpd server is 192.168.23.140 and client server is 192.168.23.141, is it my setting correct, if not, how to set it please?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar mistake.

> **Make sure to open UDP port 123 on both directions.**

If it is not open, you will get a "no server suitable for synchronization found" error. **TCP port does not work with NTP.** If you host on AWS check your security group settings.

> **Try commenting out all restrict options to isolate the error.**

Good luck.